# Make the Print dialog ask for confirmation when printing the entire document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

It happens too often that I'm only wanting to print one page, but I move too fast and the entire document starts printing.

Is there a way to set up a large Word document to verify that I only want to print the current page I'm on?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do? What do yo mean you move to fast? Why don't you use the printing dialog which sets printing the current page only?

Comment: @Pnuts, thanks for the idea, I have added an answer which is hopefully the same thing the OP is looking for too.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the default print dialogs with your own defaults. You would only add this macro to the documents that you want to have different defaults for.

```
' Override File -> Print (does not work on Word 2010)
Sub FilePrint()
    Call ShowPrintDialogWithDefault
End Sub

' Override Ctrl + P or PrintPreview in the toolbar
Sub PrintPreviewAndPrint()
    Call ShowPrintDialogWithDefault
End Sub

' Override the Quick Print button
Sub FilePrintDefault()
    Call ShowPrintDialogWithDefault
End Sub

Sub ShowPrintDialogWithDefault()
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
        .Range = wdPrintCurrentPage ' Set print current page only as the default setting
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pnuts, Thanks, I'm glad it came in helpful for you.